# Creating mixin object in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I would like to know if it's possible to create mixins.

Let's say I have page with one list of motherboards and list of cpu's, on both lists you can perform actions on items (select/deselect/remove), in addition, both lists have unique actions, for example new items can be added to motherboards list but not to cpu list.

Here's an example of how I see it.

`baseActions` contains basic functionality used by both other objects

```
var baseActions = {
    select: function(id) {
        $scope[_self].selected.push(id);
    },
    deselect: function(id) {
        var idx = $scope[_self].selected.indexOf(id);
        if (idx > 0) {
            $scope[_self].selected.splice(idx, 1)
        }

    },
    remove: function() {}
};
```

In our motherboard list we can also add new items to the list:

```
$scope.motherboardActions = {
    _self: 'motherboardActions',
    selected: [],
    add: function() {}
};
angular.extend($scope.motherboardActions, angular.copy(baseActions));
```

In our cpu list, we can order items by their name:

```
$scope.cpuActions = {
    _self: 'cpuActions',
    selected: [],
    orderBy: function() {}
};
angular.extend($scope.cpuActions, angular.copy(baseActions));
```

This example doesn't work as `_self` actually not defined when `select` is called, but I hope you get the idea.

So, I'd like to follow DRY principle and avoid creating two objects with same functions in each of them (`select`, `deselect`, `remove`), 
Is there other way doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? I also modified `$scope[_self]` in your original function since this requires *2* inputs to your function-set - $scope and _self. You can tweak it to fit your need

```
// returns your original baseActions seeded with its target.
var baseActions = function(s) {
    return{
      select: function(id) {
          s.selected.push(id);
      },
      deselect: function(id) {
          var idx = s.selected.indexOf(id);
          if (idx >= 0) { // WAS > 0 which did not appear right
              s.selected.splice(idx, 1)
          }

      },
      remove: function() {}
    };
};

$scope = {};

$scope.mbA = {
    _self: 'mbA',
    selected: [],
    add: function() {}
};

$.extend($scope.mbA, $.extend(true, {}, baseActions($scope.mbA)));

$scope.mbA.select("ABCD");
$scope.mbA.select("PQR");
$scope.mbA.select(["P","Q"]); // comparison operator needed for equality

$scope.mbA.selected; // should show 3 elements

$scope.mbA.deselect("ABCD");
$scope.mbA.selected; // should show 2 elements
```

HTH

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed! I replaced `$.extend()` with `angular.extend()` so I don't have to import `$` inside controller.